# Perl script to reach a host by ssh

Tags: perl

I'm trying to code a simple perl script to reach a host by ssh. The goal is to store the file names of the root folder in variable and print it but the script hangs after I introduce the password of the host.
would you give me a hand?

```
system(`ssh root\@10.3.64.136`);
$output = system(`ls`);
system(`exit`);
print $output;
```

Comment: Don't use `system`. Use a module designed for the purpose. https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH

Comment: or (better, usually) Net::SSH2

Comment: You could ``use IPC::Open2`` but then you'd just end up reinventing the wheel.  Use Net::SSH.  Also you need to avoid using passwords, use ssh public keys instead

Comment: use [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backquotes already invoke `system()`.  Doing it twice is not going to give the desired results.

After fixing that, your attempt still won't work: each `system()` creates a separate shell, so the second and third command are executed on your local system.  Either create a single command and feed it to `ssh` as a single argument, e.g.

```
system('ssh root@10.3.64.136 ls')
```

or

```
my @ls_output = `ssh root\@10.3.64.136 ls`;
print for @ls_output
```

or feed the commands to `ssh` as input, e.g.

```
system('echo ls | ssh root@10.3.64.136')
```

Now if you want to send arbitrary sequences of commands to `ssh`, this will be hairy.

As the comments say: using `system()` (or backquotes) for this task isn't the best idea. It is better to use a designated Perl library.